# mysql query add single quote in query

Tags: mysql

need suggestions for how to convert below query result in to:
use philips,led,and tv in to single quote.

**`insert into company_rawdata_split select 2,splits from (select NULL splits union select 'philips' union select 'led' union select 'tv') A where splits IS NOT NULL;`**

Query:

```
select concat
    ('insert into company_rawdata_split select ',id,',splits from (select NULL splits union select ',
    replace(complaint_against  ,' ',  ' union select '),') A where splits IS NOT NULL;'
    ) ProdCatQueries from company_rawdata_new
```

result

```
insert into company_rawdata_split select 2,splits from (select NULL splits union select philips union select led union select tv) A where splits IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Can you just escape the single quote? `select concat ('insert into company_rawdata_split select ',id,',splits from (select NULL splits union select \'', replace(complaint_against ,' ', '\' union select \''),'\') A where splits IS NOT NULL;' ) ProdCatQueries from company_rawdata_new`

Comment: insert into company_rawdata_split select 2,splits from (select NULL splits union select 'philips union select led union select tv') A where splits IS NOT NULL;

Comment: Just made an edit to the query above.

Comment: its gives result like above..i am trying to add quotes on philips,led and tv

Comment: Check the query in my answer. I edited my comment a few times and it probably led to some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The following should accomplish what you're attempting. It's just a matter of getting clever with the placement of some escaped single quotes `\'`

`select concat ('insert into company_rawdata_split select ',id,',splits from (select NULL splits union select \'', replace(complaint_against ,' ', '\' union select \''),'\') A where splits IS NOT NULL;' ) ProdCatQueries from company_rawdata_new`

Comment: Glad I could help! If your happy with my answer, please remember to mark it as correct.